# Adding and removing views dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to achieve effect similar to this: jsfiddle net/7pF22/ I need to be able to show more buttons/labels on demand. I thought about putting additional stuff to another view, loading xib and displaying it when receiving tap event. Unfortunately the rest of the main view is not scrolling down. So I believe that there are better ways to do this (maybe using tableview? but in my case cells doesn't have much in common)

Comment: Edit your question with proper links and some coding stuff.

Comment: Assuming this is the link that you meant: jsfiddle.net/7pF22/

Comment: yep. Including code is totally unnesesery IMO

Comment: I need some kind of idea. Currently I have no related code to show. I thought that this is clear that I'm asking for help...

Answer (score 0):

Put all views/rows in array , get index of view that you are scaling and run a loop moving all others inside UIView animation .

Comment: yeah, I thought about it too but it doesn't seem to me like a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you create a NSMutableArray to store your views.

Secondly, you could use #import  and NSClassFromString to get your view's class.

And then, add views.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"OneViewClassName",     @"TwoViewClassName"];
for (NSString *className in arr) {
  UIView *view = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:view];
  [view release];
}
```